# phonegap: is it possible to detect double touch swipe from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, cordova, swipe, gestures

I ask if a Phonegap application is able to recognize double swipe and handle related events in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, though you ought to use an API wrapper because it differs vendor to vendor. More about it http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch.html

Comment: Could I tweak the javascript code for each OS of deployment, instead of using an API wrapper? Can you give more details on this?

Comment: Sure, the choice is totally yours. It currently seems to be supported by Safari, iOS 2+ and some/many? Android phones (at least works on 2.3.3 as they claimed in the article, presumably lower version do have the support as well).